# costura.fody can't find weavers

Tags: c#, fody-costura

I installed the costura.fody nuget so that my application would have all dlls packaged into the final exe file but it brings an error that he can't  find fodyweavers.xml 
I looked everywhere what to do and the only thing I could find is to make the xml file myself.
So I created an xml file with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers VerifyAssembly="true">
  <NamedWeaver />
  <NamedWeaverFromBase />
  <ModuleWeaver />
  <Virtuosity />
</Weavers>
```

But the compiler says that fody can't find a weaver named "NamedWeaver".
I tried to change "NamedWeaver" to the same name of my namespace and it still can't find it. 
Now I can't build the solution nor know how to remove fody altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weaver is wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <Costura/>
</Weavers>
```

It is written in the documentation of Costura.Fody -> https://github.com/Fody/Costura

Comment: sorry for these simple questions, i am very new to this, should learn to first look at the documentation and only then ask questions. it worked for me thanks

Comment: No problem, I remember having lot of troubles with costura once too. It is alright to ask.